# Enable YouTube mobile live streaming

Tags: youtube, video-streaming

I have a YouTube channel: https://www.youtube.com/c/stfrancisschoolbatalaofficial. It has been marked "for kids". I am unable to stream live from my mobile even though I have more than 1K subscribers and there have been no strikes against the channel. There are no problems streaming to the same channel from the PC or from a different app. The YouTube android mobile app shows

> "Your channel does not meet our updated eligibility requirements for
> mobile streaming..."

How do I fix this?

Comment: Hi, I'm not really sure if we can't help other than suggesting [the official YouTube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853834). Have you checked the currently active account/channel on the YouTube app and make sure it's the one you want to live stream?

Comment: @AndrewT., yup, I have selected the current account.